# Compute the square of the absolute value of an expression containing a complex variable

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $$z=\lambda h$$$$\lambda\in C$$ $$h\in N$$ C is the complex set of numbers,       how to show that 
$$|1+\frac{3}{4}z|^2=(1+\frac{3}{4}z)(1+\frac{3}{4}\bar z)$$

Comment: It is easy to show that for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ you have $$|z|^2=\textrm{Re}(z)^2+\textrm{Im}(z)^2=z\cdot\bar{z}$$ In your case, just use the fact that $\overline{x+y}=\bar{x}+\bar{y}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the facts that it is generally true that $w\bar w = |w|^2$ for any $w \in \mathbb C$ and that complex conjugation "distributes over" addition and multiplication. Take $w = 1 + \frac34 z$.

Comment: An alternative substitution could be $z=\frac{4k}{3}$ or $z=\frac{4k}{3} -1$